# How to convert \textwidth to mm and use the number as a command?

Tags: macros, calculations, lengths

I am trying to convert \textwidth to other units I want and do calculations with the number (without the unit).

How does one do this?

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? A number can't be a command…

Comment: The pgfmath package does math without units.  \pgfmathparse{\textwidth/1mm} will put the value you want into \pgfmathresult.

Answer (score 4):

You can use my `calculator` package.
The `\LENGTHDIVIDE` command divides two lengths and stores result as a number in a new command, as you need.

Try this code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{calculator}
\begin{document}
   \LENGTHDIVIDE{\textwidth}{1mm}{\size} 
   \size    
\end{document}
```

In a standard a4 article `\size` returns 121.25427

Answer (score 3):

`\strip@pt` removes the unit `pt` and eTeX's `\dimexpr` can be used for the calculation:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\makeatletter
% #1: macro, which gets the result of the conversion without unit
% #2: length expression
\newcommand*{\converttomm}[2]{%
  \edef#1{%
    \strip@pt\dimexpr(#2)*2540/7227\relax % 72.27 pt = 1 in = 25.4 mm
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\converttomm{\mmTextWidth}{\textwidth}
The text width is \SI{\mmTextWidth}{\milli\meter}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 2):

Length conversion to decimal using LaTeX3:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xparse}

\ExplSyntaxOn
%\cs_new_eq:NN \calc \fp_eval:n
\cs_new_eq:NN \convertlen \dim_to_decimal_in_unit:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff 

\begin{document}

\verb|\textwidth| in \verb|pt|s: \the\textwidth

\makeatletter
\verb|1mm| in \verb|pt|s: \setlength{\@tempdima}{1mm}\the\@tempdima
\makeatother

$\frac{\texttt{\string\textwidth}}{\texttt{1mm}} = \convertlen{\textwidth}{1mm}$

\end{document}
```

The above defines the user interface `\convertlen{<fromlen>}{<tounit>}` using LaTeX3's `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit`.

Comment: Interestingly there is a significant drop in precision. Seems that the calculation does basically the quotient with `1mm` first approximated by `186467sp` which is what `\number\dimexpr 1mm\relax` returns (I obtain same result  as you if I do `\xinttheiexpr [5]\textwidth/\dimexpr 1mm\relax\relax`.) The computation as in Heiko's answer is more accurate: that would be `\xinttheiexpr [5] \textwidth*2540/(7227*65536)\relax`,  where the ratio is also in smallest terms`635/118407168`.

Comment: for `345pt`, the exact value in `mm` is `345*2540/7227=292100/2409=121.253632212536322125363221253632...`

Comment: the exact value of `1mm` in `sp` is `186467.9811...`, but TeX replaces it by `186467` as it truncates when one assigns dimensions to register. That means basically a relative error of order `0.5*10^-5`. And indeed the `\dim_to_decimal_in_unit` provides here a result which is wrong at the sixth decimal.